# Wordpress Filterable portfolio plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Anyone know any filterable wordpress plugin like the nimble 3?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plugin I developed, same functionality as nimble but easier to use.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/awesome-filterable-portfolio/

I hope that helps